# How do I restore VSCode Activity Bar back to Default

Tags: visual-studio-code

I accidentally dragged and dropped my explorer activity bar into the git icon, now the folders doesn't work like it should. I would like help getting this back to the original style since the hotkeys are now broken in this state since it has the wrong header.

I dragged things back to have a first "tile" which would have "Open Editors, Folder, Outline Timeline" like it did originally, except when I do that, it now calls the entire tile Open Editors instead of the Folders.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub Copilot: To reset the VSCode activity bar to its default state, you can follow these steps:

1. Open the Command Palette by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+P` (Windows, Linux) or `Cmd+Shift+P` (macOS).
2. Type "Reset View" and select the "View: Reset View" command.
3. This will reset the activity bar and other views to their default state.

Answer (score 0):

The command `View: Reset View Locations` resets all views, including the activity bar.